# Why is the address 1MAdS7aPszWG4EYgBpbF9mnGUi5ChbMu8d sending me Bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, dust, spam

I'm receiving 1 satoshi today from an odd address. This account has been very consistent in creating spammy transactions that distribute 1 satoshi to a lot of account. Any one know what's going on with it?

Answer (score 3):

This is spam. Point                          .

Comment: Normally people spam you message with the hope of getting you to read and then buy his product. What incentive that these people spamming the network knowing that they are losing money?

Comment: It's just the same - they hope that the increased exposure will gain them enough profitable business to exceed the costs incurred in miner fees. (Email spam has a cost to send as well - time spent composing the mail, bandwidth fees, server maintenance, etc.)